# Computed font-size is different on chrome on reload and resize

Tags: css

In chrome the computed font-size of an element is different on reload and resize while the screen has the same width.

When I first load the page on 1920px my font-size on a screen is computed as 18.65px, however when I resize my screen a bit and back to 1920px the font-size is computed as 16px. I set my html element's font-size to 62.5% and my elements's to 1.6rem, so it should be 16px.

It seems like it is only happening on chrome, on  firefox the size is computed right in both cases.

```
html, body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
} 

p.sub {
    font-size: var(--font-size-p-sub);
}

:root {
    --font-size-p-sub: 1.6rem;
}
```

[computed size after resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQWp6.png)

[computed size after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agtUf.png)

Comment: Is this true when using only Incognito windows?  Also, you don't indicate if you are using a built-in browser font, or linking another.